# Need help to write a valid regex to select text from string in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regex to select `futbol--1` and `liga-uefa--1234` from the following string:

```
/stavki/futbol--1/liga-uefa--1234/team-1-name-team-2-name--01-20-2017--123456
```

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why should `name--01` not be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only those matches are required which comes after `/`, then use `match` and `map`

```
var input = "/stavki/futbol--1/liga-uefa--1234/team-1-name-team-2-name--01-20-2017--123456";
var matches = input.match( /\/[a-z\s-]+[-]{2}\d+/g );
var output = (matches || [] ).map( s => s.substring(1) );
```